# use one variable in different js blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have variable `var valueRegionSelect = $selectOptions.eq($item.index())[0].value;` in  `$.fn.pjSelect = function() {`

I need this variable in another part:

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * map
 *******************************************************************************/
    (function() {
        var $mapForm = $('.b-map');
```

i think about use trigger, if i understand how it's work, but i guess i wrong:

```
 if (valueRegionSelect !== "") {
                        $body.trigger('regionChangeOnSelect.pj');
                    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: declare that variable globally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare that variable globally

```
var valueRegionSelect = null;

     //set the value in your function
valueRegionSelect = $selectOptions.eq($item.index())[0].value; //and use it anywhere
    /*******************************************************************************
     * map
     *******************************************************************************/
        (function() {
            var $mapForm = $('.b-map');
    if (valueRegionSelect !== "") {
                            $body.trigger('regionChangeOnSelect.pj');
                        }
```

Use this code

Comment: what if my variable show null in another block, but work in block, when i declare it.

Comment: the variable is only valid in the block where it is defined

Comment: ok, I declare it globally, but than I need to assign my variable some value in one block. And then use it in another block.

Comment: it's return value, when i call it in block, where i assign value. But it's return null when i try to call it in another block =(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28039/discussion-between-floradu88-and-stopper)